# How to Insert multiple conditions in while loop in

Tags: c#, while-loop, multiple-conditions

I want to use multiple conditions in while loop:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Select an action to perform\n");
int n1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Insert a valid method\n");
    n1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
while ((n1 == 1) || (n1 == 2));

Console.WriteLine(n1);
Console.ReadKey();
```

In here I want to check the `value n1` is equals to 1 or 2. Until the user enter n1 or 2 this should loop. The thing is I can get this to working if im using just one condition but cant get this working when there are 2 conditions. Also how to equal these values to another string?

Ex:

```cs
while ((n1 == "one") || (n1 =="two"))
```

I think theres something I didnt understand about `|| (OR) operator`. I read few solutions yet I couldnt figure it out.

Comment: Your code is doing what is expected. As long as `n1` equals 1 or `n2` equals 2 it will continue looping. If you want to stop looping once the user either entered 1 or 2 then you need to negate your expression. Either `n1 != 1 || n1 != 2` or `!(n1 == 1 || n1 == 2)`

Comment: Put the values you are interested in a `HashSet` **before** the loop. Then use `Contains`. That way you can have a single `Contains` check, regardless of the number of values you want to check.

Comment: `n1 != 1 || n1 != 2` and `!(n1 == 1 || n1 == 2)` are not equivalent. `n1 != 1 && n1 != 2` and `!(n1 == 1 || n1 == 2)` are

Answer (score 1):

You want this to loop **until the user enters 1 or 2**.

But in the code, you asked it to loop **when the user enters 1 or 2**.

So, instead of

```
while ((n1 == 1) || (n1 == 2));
```

you should write

```
while (!(n1 == 1 || n1 == 2));
```

Remaining part of the code is good, it'll work as expected.

No need to check for strings "one" and "two" as you're converting input to `Int32` in line 6.
`Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())` can't convert `string` "one" to `Integer` '1'.

Comment: Thank you !!! i tried doing  while((n1 != 1) || (n1 != 2)) and it didnt work for some reason. idk. And i just wanted to know what if i want to equal this to a string.

Comment: the string thing is more like a seperate question. rather than equaling to a int value how to check this with another string value?        
            String s1 = Console.ReadLine();
            while (!(s1 == "a" || s1 == "b"));

Comment: @lasith92 Use `Equals`. For example, you can write `String s1 = Console.ReadLine(); while (!(s1.Equals("a") || s1.Equals("b")));` Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `do....while`  with `do...until` (the latter of which is not a c# construct).

If you want an "until" sort of logic loop, use `while(true)` and use an `if` statement with the until condition to break the loop.

```
Console.WriteLine("Select an action to perform\n");
int n11 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Insert a valid method\n");
    n1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if ((n1 == 1) || (n1 == 2)) break;
}
```

An alternative is to keep the while construct but invert the logic. This isn't my favorite answer because it may cause the logic to become less clear.

```
Console.WriteLine("Select an action to perform\n");
int n11 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Insert a valid method\n");
    n1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
while ((n1 != 1) && (n1 != 2));
```

Comment: while ((n1 != 1) && (n1 != 2));   can you explain why you've used && here? And that clarified the issue.

Comment: It means "continue only if the user didn't enter a 1 and didn't enter a 2." When you flip Boolean logic, `or`s become `and`s.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is this:

```
while ((n1 == 1) || (n1 == 2))
```

This code states that the loop should be repeated / continue if `n1 == 1` or `n1 == 2`. What you actually want is to repeat where `n1` isn't equal to either of them:

```
while (n1 != 1 && n1 != 2)
```

This states that if `n1` isn't `1`, and `n1` isn't `2`, then it should loop. If this statement isn't true, the loop will exit and your code will move on to `Console.WriteLine(n1);`.

Note that `n1 != 1 && n1 != 2` is the opposite of `n1 == 1 || n1 == 2`.

Comment: && will need both to be true right? If i want either n1=1 or 2 it should exit.... if i want just 1 to be true it should be && or || operater?

Comment: Yes, both conditions will have to be true. That is to say: if `n1 != 1` returns false, and `n1 != 2` returns false, the will exit, otherwise it will go back to `Console.WriteLine("Insert a valid method\n");`. Remember `!=` means "not equal", so in words it reads "if n1 is not equal to 1, and n1 is not equal to 2, continue the loop".

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using *infinite loop* `while(true) {...}` which we `break` on valid input (please, note `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32` - we don't want *exception* on input like `"bla-bla-bla"`):

```
// Let's be nice and show expected user response - 1 or 2
Console.WriteLine("Select an action to perform (1, 2)\n");

int n1;

while (true) {
  // If user input is a valid i.e.
  //   1. Input is valid integer - int.TryParse returns true
  //   2. User input is either 1 or 2
  // we break the loop and start business logic; otherwise keep asking  
  if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n1) && ((n1 == 1) || (n1 == 2)))
    break;

  // Again, let's be nice and help user
  Console.WriteLine("Insert a valid method (either 1 or 2)\n"); 
}

Console.WriteLine(n1);
Console.ReadKey();
```